# Numeric type showing in weird form

Tags: postgresql, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm using PyQt + Qt Designer and I've connected it to my PostgreSQL database. When I try to show records from my database with this code:

```
if self.Kirurg_checkBox.isChecked():
                     Kirurg_query = QSqlQueryModel()
                     Kirurg_query.setQuery("SELECT * FROM kirurg")
                     global view_Kirurg
                     view_Kirurg = QtGui.QTableView()
                     view_Kirurg.setModel(Kirurg_query)
                     view_Kirurg.setWindowTitle('kirurg')
                     view_Kirurg.show()
```

Numeric columns look like this: 2.3177e+09, while they should look like they look in my database, which is like this: 2317698765. This worked fine until I've changed (inside PostgreSQL) column type from character(11) to numeric(11,0) (it was required of me). Is there a way to make those columns show value in normal way, not this weird one?

**EDIT:**

I've put if column == 0 (cause that's where the weird value is, but also at last column, column 4). And it completely deletes my first column (column 0), it fixes last column (column 4) so it looks nicely, and it gives me a lot of error lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toString'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\bazapodataka.py", line 50, in paint
    textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
....
....
....
```

And bunch more of them, all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use [`QItemDelegate`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html) to formatting your data.

**Short explain**

Set delegate in your data column index (In this case 2) and put it in `QtGui.QTableView`

```
class QCustomDelegate (QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 2:
            textQString = '%.0f' % indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            # textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString() # For some version PyQt4-4.11.1-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.6-x64
            self.drawDisplay(painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect, textQString)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)
```

and

```
if self.Kirurg_checkBox.isChecked():
    Kirurg_query = QSqlQueryModel()
    Kirurg_query.setQuery("SELECT * FROM kirurg")
    global view_Kirurg
    view_Kirurg = QtGui.QTableView()
    view_Kirurg.setItemDelegate(QCustomDelegate())
    view_Kirurg.setModel(Kirurg_query)
    view_Kirurg.setWindowTitle('kirurg')
    view_Kirurg.show()
```

---

**Long explain** (Recommend read this)

1) First, Your need to know what your formatting data in column. This is my data example;

```
+------------+------------+-----------------+
|    Name    |   Owner    |      Value      |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Sushi      | Lawson     |      2.3177e+12 |
| Yakisoba   | Lawson     |      1.4141e+12 |
| Snack      | 7-11       |      3.1446e+12 |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

OK, I want to show integer number format no exponent format at column 3.

2) Set your format at specified your column index. This case is column 3 to integer number format by implement in [`QItemDelegate.paint (self, QPainter painter, QStyleOptionViewItem option, QModelIndex index)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html#paint). Also, your can custom your format your want, such as, xxxx.xx $, etc. In this case, convert to string to easy to show integer number.

```
class QCustomDelegate (QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 2:
            textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
            self.drawDisplay(painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect, textQString)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)
```

3) Put your `QCustomDelegate` to your `QtGui.QTableView` or subclass in [`QAbstractItemView`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html) by method [`QAbstractItemView.setItemDelegate (self, QAbstractItemDelegate delegate)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate). Like this;

```
myQTableView = QtGui.QTableView()
myQTableView.setItemDelegate(QCustomDelegate())
```

Final, data should be look like this;

```
+------------+------------+-----------------+
|    Name    |   Owner    |      Value      |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Sushi      | Lawson     |   2317700000000 |
| Yakisoba   | Lawson     |   1414100000000 |
| Snack      | 7-11       |   3144600000000 |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QCustomDelegate (QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 2:
            textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
            self.drawDisplay(painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect, textQString)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

class QCustomTreeWidget (QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setItemDelegate(QCustomDelegate())

    def addMenu (self, name, owner, value, parentQTreeWidgetItem = None):
        if parentQTreeWidgetItem == None:
            parentQTreeWidgetItem = self.invisibleRootItem()
        currentQTreeWidgetItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parentQTreeWidgetItem)
        currentQTreeWidgetItem.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, name)
        currentQTreeWidgetItem.setData(1, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, owner)
        currentQTreeWidgetItem.setData(2, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, value)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomTreeWidget = QCustomTreeWidget()
myQCustomTreeWidget.addMenu('Sushi',    'Lawson', 2.3177e+012)
myQCustomTreeWidget.addMenu('Yakisoba', 'Lawson', 1.4141e+012)
myQCustomTreeWidget.addMenu('Snack',    '7-11',   3.1446e+012)
myQCustomTreeWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: Meybe return of `indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)` is float data-type (Not `QVariant`). OK, convert it in string. Check my edit post. I have question, What your version of PyQt ? Thanks.

Comment: It's working now! You're lifesaver, once again :). I'm using PyQt4, this version: PyQt4-4.11.1-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.6-x64.exe. Let me just ask you one more thing. I've put if column == 2, and it's working for all my numeric columns, why is that? For example, it's working for my ID column (column 0), and my phone number column (column 4)?

Comment: Because displaying items from a custom model in a standard view. Default show is string value or sometime in exponent format value. Is in mechanism of `QItemDelegate`.

Or easy to tell is, we create custom show data, All data will show string format by default.